# Copying to cells without having to select them first

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently trying to use VBA to copy some cells from one location to another and because I'm new to VBA I was wondering if anyone could help me make my code a bit more efficient I know there must be a way to copy to a cell without having to select the cell and then copy to it

```
For i = 1 To dataSheet.Range("A" & dataSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    dataSheet.Range("A" & i & ":" & "CT" & i).Copy
    Set rCell = dataSheet.Range("C" & i)
    pasteSheet.Activate
    If rCell = condition1 Then
        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("CU" & rowLoop2).Select
            ActiveSheet.paste
        End With
```

Comment: read this -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760.aspx

Comment: You could gain a little efficiency by moving the "copy" line inside your "If". Alternatively, rather than checking each line to see if it satisfies condition1 and only carrying out a copy & paste if it does, you could (as suggested above) copy the entire range, then delete the rows from your pasteSheet that don't satisfy the condition.

Comment: You may find some pointers here : http://www.excelitems.com/2010/12/optimize-vba-code-for-faster-macros.html

Comment: I didn't include the other parts of the if statement but there are some else if sections that copy the range to different cells if it meets other conditions. Would putting the copy inside each if & else if be more efficient I just did it this way because it was less lines of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options. Either use the `.PasteSpecial` method, or you can just reference the original range and set the new range to it's value.

```
.Range("CU" & rowLoop2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
```

With the setting values option, you have to define the whole range which the values should fill.

```
Range("A3:E3").Value = Range("A1:E1").Value
```

If you just used `Range("A3").Value = Range("A1:E1").Value` only cell `A3` would be populated, and it would take th value from cell `A1`. Hope this helps.

Edit: it's worth noting that you do not have to change sheets to paste either. Your code could be amended to the below:

```
With dataSheet
    For i = 1 To .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A" & i & ":" & "CT" & i).Copy
        Set rCell = .Range("C" & i)
        If rCell = condition1 Then
            pasteSheet.Range("CU" & rowLoop2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for thanks very much